# Everything was working fine I didn't change any code and suddenly Getting Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to login in my website, I am using CodeIgniter framework in the models folder I created User_model.php and function called authenticate user and that is the code:

```
public function authenticate_user($us, $pass){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '".$us."' AND  password = '".$pass."' LIMIT 1");
    return $query->row();
}
```

in the controller folder I created a user.php with function called login
and that is part of the code:

```
public function login(){

    if($_POST){
        $result = $this->user_model->authenticate_user($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);

        // If the username and password found
        if(!empty($result)){
            // Set userdata
            $userdata = [       
                                    'id' => $result->id,
                'username' => $result->username,
                'password' => $result->password,
                'logged_in' => TRUE
            ];
```

the error is in the line which contains 'id' => $result->id I don't know why it was working fine with no errors and I didn't change anything and suddenly it gives me that error

The database contains a table called users with 3 attributes id and it is auto incremented, username and password that's it, by the way the website is on a free host and giving me this error when ever I try to login.

Any help please just to understand why I am getting this error.

[image: error message]

Comment: Just a side note ... this "authentication" you have going is RIPE for SQL injections. You need to fix that.

Comment: I hope you are not storing plan password in database you should be using some thing like this to create password http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php then to verify it use a callback http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = '".$us."' AND password = '".$pass."' LIMIT 1");
```

Maybe you forget the ID column
Hope this help you :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you don't have `id` field in your query. Change your `authenticate_user` method to:

```
public function authenticate_user($us, $pass){
    // add id field
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = '".$us."' AND  password = '".$pass."' LIMIT 1");
    return $query->row();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how CodeIgniter populates the Domain Objects but you're missing the id field on the SQL query

```
SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '".$us."' AND  password = '".$pass."' LIMIT 1
```

You're only retrieving username and password. Get the id field too:

```
SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = '".$us."' AND  password = '".$pass."' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First don't store plan passwords in database use this method to create passwords

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Make sure password column varchar 255

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

> And also I would not put password in session either.

```
<?php

class User extends CI_Controller {

public function login(){

   if($this->input->post()){

    if ($this->verifyPassword($this->input->post('password'), $this->input->post('username')))

        $userdata = $this->getUser($this->input->post('username'));


        if ($userdata)
        {
            $sessiondata = array(
                'username' => $userdata['username'],
                'id' => $userdata['id'],
                'logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);

             redirect(base_url('controllername'));

        }


   }

}

public function verifyPassword($password, $username)
{
    $stored_password = $this->getPassword($username);

    if (password_verify($password, $stored_password))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

public function getPassword($username)
{
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $user_query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
    if ($user_query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $user_query->row()->password;
    }

    return false;
}

public function getUser($username)
{
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $user_query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');

    return $user_query->row_array();
}

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I know that I have to save passwords encrypted I just didn't reach that step yet but thank you for your concern.